# How can I in-place construct an object of some class in an std::unorderd_map?

Tags: c++, qt, std, unordered-map, qgraphicsitem

I want to store a number of objects `MyItem`, **derived from `Qt::QGraphicsItem`**, in an `std::unordered_map`. As I understood, `Qt::QGraphicsItem` **is none-copyable**: copy constructor is private.

This is fine; I don't want to copy `MyItem`. But I would need to construct `MyItem` in-place. Assuming `MyItem` has this constructor signature:

```
MyItem::MyItem(int a, double b, std::string c);
```

And this is my `std::unordered_map`:

```
std::unordered_map< KeyType, MyItem > myItemMap;
```

What is wrong with this line, where `KeyType` is copyable and constructed before the emplacement:

```
myItemMap.emplace( correspondingKey, MyItem(3, 3.14, "hello") );
```

I get this error (cut):

```
use of deleted function 'MyItem::MyItem(const MyItem&)'
  : first(std::forward<_U1>(__x)), second(__y) { }
                                             ^
'MyItem::MyItem(const MyItem&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:

'QGraphicsItem::QGraphicsItem(const QGraphicsItem&)' is private
```

How does the arguments of `myItemMap.emplace(...)` must look like?

Comment: Use `myItemMap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(correspondingKey), std::forward_as_tuple(3, 3.14, "hello"));` instead

Answer (score 3):

You're constructing a `MyItem` value which `emplace` then tries to copy. The point of the `emplace` functions is to leave the construction to the `map`. It gets complicated because you need to pass a `pair`, where you want to defer construction of `second`.

```
myItemMap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
          std::forward_as_tuple(correspondingKey),
          std::forward_as_tuple(3, 3.14, "hello"));
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace.

Comment: This is a working solution, but when they said C++11 would make C++ easier to use, I think they took us for fools.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Well, you can at least do it now - in C++08 you couldn't. And C++17 will provide `try_emplace` which reduces the ugliness considerably. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/try_emplace

Answer (score 1):

You code will work if you add a move constructor to `MyItem`:

```
MyItem(MyItem&& old)
    : Base(old.parentItem())
{
    for (QGraphicsItem* child : old.childItems()) {
        child->setParentItem(this);
    }
    old.setParentItem(nullptr);
}
```

Then the instance will be automatically moved and not copied.

Comment: That would also mean that `QGraphicsItem` would need to have a move constructor? Which, according to the documentation (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qgraphicsitem.html) it does not (or its not obvious to me).

Comment: @dani: No, it does not require `QGraphicsItem` to have a move constructor.  It merely requires that `MyItem` does.  It may be possible to implement a `MyItem` move constructor, e.g. using the regular constructor of `QGraphicsItem`.  I have added a possible implementation to my answer.